# How to retrieve elements in foreach loop in Mule4?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mulesoft

I have defined a variable to keep application/json collection.

My original payload contain following json block;

```
"amendments": {
    "amendmentId": ["8a9a84b76b5a5a59016b687bae35012e",
                "8a9a84b76b5a5a59016b6888e90e0144"]
                }

<set-variable value="#[payload..amendmentId[1]]" doc:name="AmendmentIds" doc:id="03b6c46a-fc7b-43d4-b23a-502146ef0b13" variableName="amendmentids"/>
<logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="6a1ad892-65f9-4dd2-9891-bdf3ad64c908" message="#[vars.amendmentids]" />
```

It prints as;

```
[
  "8a9a84b76b5a5a59016b687bae35012e",
  "8a9a84b76b5a5a59016b6888e90e0144"
]
```

Then I use ForEach loop to define few process logic for each Id,
Within foreach loop how I can get, each above id?
I used,`vars.amendmentids[vars.counter]]`, but getting following error[1]

```
<foreach doc:name="For Each" doc:id="7b741315-aa28-4704-82f0-629c21d93853" collection="#[vars.amendmentids]">
            <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="049c3137-2f92-4077-8e3f-b26516cc5528" message="#[vars.amendmentids[vars.counter]]"/>

        </foreach>
```

[1]

```
Message               : "Internal execution exception while executing the script, this is most probably a bug, file an issue with the script and the input data.
Caused by:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to infer a output media type as more than one is being used: application/json,application/java please specify using: output <your mime-type> --- <expr>
    at org.mule.weave.v2.el.MuleDataWeaveHelper$.inferImplicitOutput(MuleDataWeaveHelper.scala:69)
.............
" evaluating expression: "vars.amendmentids[vars.counter]".
Error type            : MULE:EXPRESSION
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by defining output mime type like;

```
<logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="049c3137-2f92-4077-8e3f-b26516cc5528" message="#[output application/java --- vars.amendmentids[vars.counter - 1]]"/>
```